# A limit property of the integral of $\sin(x) / x^{1 + b}$ and little $o$ notation

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Suppose $b > 1$ it is clear that the integral
$$\int_{y}^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{1 + b} } \ dx \to \infty, \ y \to 0^+ \ .$$
However I am interested in showing that there exists a constant $C$ such that
$$ \int_{y}^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{1 + b} } \ dx  = C y^{1 - b} + o (1) \ .$$
I am not that used to little $o$-notation but to my understanding I wish to show that there exists a constant $C$ such that
$$ \lim_{y \to 0^+} \left( \int_{y}^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{1 + b} } \ dx - C y^{1 - b} \right) = 0 \ .$$
My problem is that this seems to be an "exact" rate of the divergence of the integral so I have no idea how to approach this limit.

Comment: Write the integrand as $$\frac{1}{x^b} + \biggl(\frac{\sin x}{x} - 1\biggr)x^{-b}.$$ What do you know about $\frac{\sin x}{x} - 1$?

Comment: That was a great hint, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may use, as $y \to 0^+$,
$$
x-\frac{x^3}6\le\sin x\le x-\frac{x^3}6+\frac{x^5}{120},\quad x \in [y,1].
$$ giving
$$
\int_{y}^1 \frac{dx}{x^{b} }-\frac16\int_{y}^1 \frac{dx}{x^{b-2} }\le\int_{y}^1 \frac{\sin x}{x^{1 + b} } \ dx\le \int_{y}^1 \frac{dx}{x^{b} }-\frac16\int_{y}^1 \frac{dx}{x^{b-2} }x+\frac1{120}\int_{y}^1 \frac{dx}{x^{b-5} }x
$$ or, as $y \to 0^+$,
$$
\int_{y}^1 \frac{\sin x}{x^{1 + b} } \ dx=  \frac1{b-1}y^{1-b} + o(1).
$$